# Trace touched code lines in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

Can I achieve something like this in visual studio debugger:

In c++ file:

```
breakpoint 1 
int a = 3;
if (a>4)
{
    cout<<s;
}
else
{
    cout<<a;
}
a++;
breakpoint 2
```

I want to get log which lines of code was touched between breakpoint 1 and breakpoint 2:

```
int a = 3;
if (a>4)
    cout<<a;
a++;
```

Or is it possible with something else?

Comment: For `gcc/g++`, you have `__FUNCTION__`, `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` (not sure about the last one). These are macros, that give you information about the place of the log. You can try them in VS or search for some analogues.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to use ;-) Thx anyway ;-)

Comment: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are standard. Visual Studio also supports `__FUNCTION__`. See [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/b0084kay.aspx) page.

Comment: @piotrek - then I have misunderstood your question? You want log on each like, without manually putting it there?

Comment: I want to log (for ouput window for example) without making anything with my code, like adding printfs with macros.